# Auto populating textbox with incremented column value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a dropdownlist of ID=ddlDept which shows the department from a column named DId and table named Department. Under that selected department there are students with StudentID  from the column named StudentID and table named registration which i have done by inner join operation. Now I want to auto populate a textbox in a aspx webform with the incremented StudentID by selecting from ddlDept.

Before selecting ddlDept Suppose i had ddlDept of 02 and the last studentID in that **"02" department is 0705044.**
Now if I **select "02" from ddlDept** then the **textbox for StudentID** must populate with the value of **0705045**

Also if the Student ID is 0405089 then by selecting the ddlDept it must populate with 0405089.

That means increment will be of the last 2 digits only.

I am very stuck.Suggest with sample code.Thnx in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? You say you're stuck but if there's no code to show where you're stuck, how far do you think we'll get?

Comment: That means increment will be of the last 2 digits only ?? And if you have 0405099, it will be 3 no ?

Comment: i have no clue how to do it..@YannickMeeus..plz help with some clue
and if i input **05** the studentID must be 040590@Benji_9989